# python regex command to extract data excluding comment line

Tags: python, regex

I need to extract data in a data file beginning with the letter 
"U" 
or 
"L" 
and exclude comment lines beginning with character "/" .

Example:

```
/data file FLG.dat
UAB-AB      LRD1503     / reminder latches
```

I used a regex pattern in the python program which results in only capturing the comment lines. I'm only getting comment lines but not the identity beginning with character.

Comment: if file_path != "":
    #pattern to search comment lines in the text file
    #pattern = "[^A-Za-z0-9-]/.+"
    data = read_file(file_path)  
    find_str = re.findall(pattern , data)
    for x in find_str:
        print(x)    
else:
    print("no file selected")
    sys.exit()

Comment: Please add your code [into the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57741069/edit) and make sure it's well-formatted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`^([UL].+?)(?:/.*|)$`](https://regex101.com/r/eKW5Zz/6). Code:

```
import re

s = """/data file FLG.dat
UAB-AB      LRD1503     / reminder latches
LAB-AB      LRD1503     / reminder latches
SAB-AB      LRD1503     / reminder latches"""
lines = re.findall(r"^([UL].+?)(?:/.*|)$", s, re.MULTILINE)
```

If you want to delete spaces at the end of string you can use list comprehension with same regular expression:

```
lines = [match.group(1).strip() for match in re.finditer(r"^([UL].+)/.*$", s, re.MULTILINE)]
```

OR you can edit regular expression to not include spaces before slash [`^([UL].+?)(?:\s*/.*|)$`](https://regex101.com/r/eKW5Zz/7):

```
lines = re.findall(r"^([UL].+?)(?:\s*/.*|)$", s, re.MULTILINE)
```

Comment: `^([UL].+)/.*$` doesn't look right. First, try it against ' 'Uabc/xyz/def'. Second, it  only matches lines with comments.

Comment: @RonaldAaronson, I agree with second, it's a logical mistake and it's fixed. About second, I prefer to use logic of comments in code - first occurrence of comment marker starts comment block.

Answer (score 1):

In case the comments in your data lines are optional here's a regular expression that covers both types, lines with or without a comment.

The regular expression for that is `R"^([UL][^/]*)"`
(edited, original RE was `R"^([UL][^/]*)(/.*)?$"`)
The first group is the data you want to extract, the 2nd (optional group) would catch the comment if any.

This example code prints only the 2 valid data lines.

```
import re

lines=["/data file FLG.dat",
       "UAB-AB      LRD1503     / reminder latches",
       "UAB-AC      LRD1600",
       "MAB-AD      LRD1700     / does not start with U or L"
       ]

datare=re.compile(R"^([UL][^/]*)")

matches = ( match.group(1).strip() for match in ( datare.match(line) for line in lines) if match)

for match in matches:
    print(match)
```

Note how `match.group(1).strip()` extracts the first group of your RE and strip() removes any trailing spaces in your match

Also note that you can replace `lines` in this example with a file handle and it would work the same way

If the `matches =` line looks too complicated, it's an efficient way for writing this:

```
for line in lines:
    match = datare.match(line)
    if match:
        print(match.group(1).strip())
```

Comment: And what does the `(/.*)?$` portion of your regex contribute to the final result unless you wanted to know what the comment was?

Comment: I wasn't clear: `(/.*)?$` isn't necessary unless you want to know *if* there is a comment and *what* it is.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The 2nd match group is not needed (unless you need to know whether there is a comment or what it is). I updated my answer and the example still works.